# How variable can be accessible outside the for loop

Tags: javascript

In the code below, I have declared variable `i` on for loop , and trying to access variable `i` and I can get the last updated value of `i`, how.

```js
for(var i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
   console.log(i);
}

console.log(i,'outside');
```

Comment: Your code as posted works. What is it that you're *really* doing?

Comment: @ Pointy yes it works ,but I was trying to understand how that variable i posses that value outside the loop.

Comment: `var` declarations create variables that are visible throughout the function they appear in.

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable-in-jav)

Answer (score 8):

[The `var` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) declares a variable in the scope of **the current function**, not the current block (which is what [the `let` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) is for).

After the `for` loop, you are still in the same function, so the variable still exists (with whatever value it was last set to).

(NB: For the purposes of `var`, the code which runs outside of any function is effectively treated as being in a function of its own).

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are using `var`, and that's exactly a `var` type should do!

We have `var` and `let`, let's see how they work.

when you declare your variable like this :

```
let something;
```

You only access `something` in that very scope (for example your own `for` loop), and outside the scope, you cannot have it. On the other hand, when you are using `var` type, like this :

```
var something;
```

You are able to use this variable outside the scope ( again like your own `for` loop )

Notice that we are not talking about global variables. we are just talking about scopes.

If you rather declare a global variable, just use `var` in the global scope.